# Do I need vti_conf in a PHP site?

Tags: php, iis

My client has PHP running on an IIS server, I know these vti_conf files are important for .NET pages, but my site is completely PHP (and could and should run completely on Apache).

Is there any reason I should keep these folders (this site will only ever be PHP) and if not is there some way I can make IIS stop producing them on this specific site/directory? They're doubling the file count in my directories.

Comment: You definitely do not need them. As to how to remove them ... try removing any references to ASP.NET in site config (somehow I did get rid of them in my setup).

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and so far they haven't reappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Since the PHP site was the only one on the server, removing the vti_conf files had no effect and the server was eventually migrated to Apache.